# How do I delete a fork in CodePlex with Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, codeplex

I know GitHub has spoiled me, but shouldn't this be easy?

I'm not able to find a way to delete a fork I created on someone else's project. I'm the fork owner.

Is the answer is going to be the same as [How to Delete Project](http://codeplex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Start%20a%20Project#Delete), email them? Boy if I worked at CodePlex I would code a better way pretty quick to stop all those emails :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering a fork is your own project, and that the [ticket 25808](http://codeplex.codeplex.com/workitem/25808) ("Deleting a mercurial fork") opened in March 2011 has yet to receive any answer...
the "[How to delete a project](http://codeplex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Start%20a%20Project#Delete)" (that you mention) remains your only option.